# Vuex with Nuxt Error: this.$store is undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm coding along with a Nuxt course and I got the following error while of course it worked in the tutorial.

`TypeError: can't access property "dispatch", this.$store is undefined`

store/index.js file:

```
import Vuex from "vuex";

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: { loadedPosts: [] },

    mutations: {
      setPosts(state, posts) {
        state.loadedPosts = posts;
      },
    },

    actions: {
      setPosts(vuexContext, posts) {
        vuexContext.commit("setPosts", posts);
      },
    },

    getters: {
      loadedPosts(state) {
        console.log("imhere");
        return state.loadedPosts;
      },
    },
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

the `script` in posts/index.vue file:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loadedPosts: [{id: "1",title: "First Post"}],
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("setPosts", this.loadedPosts);
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try it on a `@click`. Also, not sure what is wrong here but maybe try to use a `mapActions` helper?

Comment: if you are using nuxt js then no need to import `Vuex`. You have to make index.js file in store folder in Nuxt project repo.

Comment: are you importing and using your store in main.js for new Vue instance creation ?

Comment: @kissu tried that and didnt work too,

Comment: @JinalSomaiya Didn't know that thank you but that wasnt the root cause, i deleted the file and started again and it worked dont know why

Comment: @AnantVikramSingh I can't understand fully what you mean. I made a file named index.js in the store folder

Comment: you have to then import that file in main.js or location where you initialise new Vue instance and after that it should be working.